# How to execute SQL query in bookshelf

Tags: bookshelf.js

Anyone know how to execute SQL query in bookshelf?
Something like:

```
bookshelf.query(sql).then(function(results) {
    callback(null, results);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't execute raw queries in Bookshelf.js. If you want so, use Knex.js (used by Bookshelf) this way :

```
const myId = 42;
knex.raw('SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = ?', [myId])
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
});
```

Bookshelf.js is meant to be an ORM, where you declare each table inside your Javascript project and uses these models to retrieve data from your database.

Here's an example.

```
const Company = db.bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'companys',
    hunters: function employees() {
        return this.hasMany(Employee, 'company_id');
    }
});

const Employee = db.bookshelf.Model.extend({
    tableName: 'employees',
    company: function company() {
        return this.belongsTo(Company);
    }
});

Company.where({ id: 42 }).fetch([ withRelated: 'employees' ])
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
})
```

Comment: You are missing a '.' before the then in your knew.raw code
`const myId = 42;
knex.raw('SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE id = ?', [myId])
.then(result => {
    console.log(result);
}, error => {
    console.log(error);
});`